# actionDone for EditText without singleLine option

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I need to set the actiondone for my edittext without set the singleLine oprions (i need the input in multiple line). How can i do it?

that's the code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+edit_text/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Titolo"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+edit_text/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Inserisci la nota"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: The text is able to be entered, but it does the sideways-scrolling thing rather than expanding the EditText field vertically. If you save that text and display it somewhere else then it is there, but just not displaying in a multi-line format.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution
Set on your view programmatically

```
mEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
mEditText.setImeActionLabel(getResources().getString(R.string.done), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

The xml file will be:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The solution was found here:
https://gist.github.com/Dogesmith/2b98df97b4fca849ff94

Answer (score 0):

Since SingleLine = false/true is deprecated. Apply below code. It worked for me.

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```